# Using exports in nodejs to return a value from function in a function

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nodes

I've been doing some reading on modularizing my code and decided to export some functions to a separate file and include them in my main function once it's called. Only my config of my website is not returning if I'm calling it:

```
// Export from my controller
// File: Controller.js
exports.site_config = function(company, data) {

   siteConfig.find({"company" : company}, function data (err, siteConfig, data) {
    // Console.log(siteConfig[0]) // Works
    return siteConfig[0] // This return is not working
    })
  // Only here returns works....
}

// File: Index.js
const siteController = require('../controllers/site');
console.log(siteController.site_config('company2')) // nothing return
```

Answer (score 0):

your find function return a callback you can do something like this:

```
// Export from my controller
// File: Controller.js
exports.site_config = function(company, data, callback) {

   siteConfig.find({"company" : company}, function (err, siteConfig, data) {
    callback(siteConfig[0]);
    })
}

// File: Index.js
const siteController = require('../controllers/site');
console.log(siteController.site_config('company2', null,function (result) {
  console.log(result)
}))
```

Comment: Callback is not an function...

```Server started on port 3000
events.js:173
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: callback is not a function

Answer (score 0):

In nodejs- express js , you need to pass function as callback .

when result is available or some error occurred in code return them in callback;

// File: Controller.js

write your function inside module.exports :

```
module.exports = {
   var site_config = function(company,callback) {
      siteConfig.find({"company" : company}, function(err, data) 
      {
         if(!err && data){
          // no error and data is available , so pass err as null and data as data[0] to callback
         return callback(null,data[0]);
         }else{
          // error occured , pass err as err and data = null to callback
          return callback(err,null);
         }
      });
   }
}
```

in you File: Index.js , require file Controller.js

```
const siteController = require('../controllers/Controller');
siteController.site_config('company2',function(err,data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). Synchronous code can be transformed to asynchronous but not vice versa.

Mongoose has been supporting promises for a long time, callback API is legacy. This is a use case for them.

A module should export a promise of configuration object. A more concise way to retrieve a single document is `findOne`:

```
exports.site_config = function(company, data) {
   return siteConfig.findOne({"company" : company});
};
```

And is consumed as a promise. There should be promise chain, up to to application entry point if needed:

```
// inside `async` function:
const siteController = require('../controllers/site');
const config = await siteController.site_config('company2');
```

Comment: It exports only the function now.... 

`aiases: {},
  subpaths: {},
  virtuals:
   { id:
      VirtualType { path: 'id', getters: [Array], setters: [], options: {} } },
  singleNestedPaths: {},
  nested: {},
  inherits: {},
  callQueue: [],
  _indexes: [],
  methods: {},
  methodOptions: {},
  statics: {},
  tree:
   { site_title: { type: [Function: String], required: false },
     site_slogan: { type: [Function: String], required: false },`

Comment: What do you expect it to export? What you listed is not a function, it's Mongoose document. In case you need it to be plain object, use `siteConfig.findOne({"company" : company}).lean()`