# Await asynchronous function before module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js

I have a NextJS app and am using next-routes to handle all routing.

My routing module currently looks like this:

```
const routes = require('next-routes')();
const { getEntries } = require('../data/contentful');

module.exports = async () => {
  const globalSettings = await getEntries({
    content_type: 'globalSettings',
  });

  routes
    .add('caseStudies', `/${globalSettings.fields.caseStudiesSlug}`, 'caseStudies')
    .add('caseStudy', `/${globalSettings.fields.caseStudiesSlug]}/:slug`, 'caseStudy')
    .add('home', `/`, 'index')
    .add('page', `/:slug*`, 'page'));

  return routes;
};
```

I can get this working for server side, but to use next-routes on client side, I need this module to immediately return the routes object rather than an async function. e.g.

```
const routes = require('next-routes')();
const { getEntries } = require('../data/contentful');

// Do this first, then module.exports
const globalSettings = await getEntries({
  content_type: 'globalSettings',
});

module.exports = routes
  .add('caseStudies', `/${globalSettings.fields.caseStudiesSlug}`, 'caseStudies')
  .add('caseStudy', `/${globalSettings.fields.caseStudiesSlug]}/:slug`, 'caseStudy')
  .add('home', `/`, 'index')
  .add('page', `/:slug*`, 'page'));
```

This doesn't work because `await` must be inside an async function. How can I complete my async API call before doing my module.exports of the routes object?

Comment: I'm not sure you can, since `require` is synchronous, it can't wait for an API call to end to import your module. BTW, let's  say your server answers in dozen of seconds, what do you expect it to do ? If it could wait for your api call to end, it would probably froze your server until it's done.

Comment: Why again does it need to be synchronous?

Comment: @KevinB Because the next-routes object can be imported on client side and destructured like so `import { Link } from '../routes';`

Comment: wait... so the only reason you want is synchronous is so you can destructure it? that’s a bit silly imo.

Comment: @KevinB This is how the next-routes package works. It's a popular addition to NextJS and not something I have control over.

Comment: I meant it's silly as destructing isn't a necessary thing for you to do there. There must be some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of [this renowned problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). Synchronous code can be transformed to asynchronous but not vice versa.

As shown in [this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54690224/using-exports-in-nodejs-to-return-a-value-from-function-in-a-function/54691449#54691449), promises should be used up to application entry point if needed:

```
module.exports = (async () => {
  const globalSettings = await getEntries({
    content_type: 'globalSettings',
  });

  return routes
  .add('caseStudies', `/${globalSettings.fields.caseStudiesSlug}`, 'caseStudies')
  .add('caseStudy', `/${globalSettings.fields.caseStudiesSlug]}/:slug`, 'caseStudy')
  .add('home', `/`, 'index')
  .add('page', `/:slug*`, 'page'));
})();
```

This module also exports a promise so it needs to be chained in a module that depends on it.

There is [a proposal for top-level `await`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) that is intended to provide syntactic sugar for this recipe.

Comment: Top level await is exactly what I need!

Comment: Sadly, it isn't even near to being approved and implemented natively. Exporting async IIFEs like the answer shows and importing them with `await require('async-module')` is what we have now. You can see that the proposal actually describes this, https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await#workaround-export-a-promise-to-represent-initialization

Comment: I'm struggling to work out a solution to my problem then. Basically on server side I need to do my globalSettings API call and build the routes object. Then on client side, I want to be able to access that routes object without doing the API call again.

Comment: I don't use Next myself. If you have problems accessing an object from server side on client side then that's more specific problem. Basically this is done by rendering index page with `<script>window.__MY_DATA__ = 'data from server side'</script>` but there could be solutions that are specific to Next.